# Android OnCreateContextMenu separator not showing

Tags: android

Below here is my code regarding onCreateContextMenu and the problem with this is that since there are no lines or separators that distinguish headers and items, it still looks bad even if I change text size and use customized header view that has the underline.
I searched for practices out in the google and I followed it, however, it creates none of lines or separators to clarify which one is a header or which one is the item.

What did I do wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        UsEditText title = new UsEditText(root);
        title.setText(R.string.common_delete);
        title.setTextSize(40);
        title.setPadding(0,3,0,2);
        menu.setHeaderView(title);
        menu.add(100, v.getId(), 100, R.string.clear));
        menu.add(200, -1, 100, getString(R.string.common_clear_all));
    }
```

Right now, I use my customized EditText with underline with it, but if I do choose to use plain EditText, it shows no separator.

[image]

Comment: Where is your screenshot?

Comment: @PratikButani just added screenshot.